# SQL date difference using the same column based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to calculate the days since the last different order so for example let's say I have the following table:

```
cust_id|Product_id|Order_date|
1      |a         |10/02/2020|
2      |b         |10/01/2020|
3      |c         |09/07/2020|
4      |d         |09/02/2020|
1      |a         |08/29/2020|
1      |f         |08/02/2020|
2      |g         |07/01/2020|
3      |t         |06/06/2020|
4      |j         |05/08/2020|
1      |w         |04/20/2020|
```

I want to find the difference between the most recent date and the previous date that has a product ID that doesn't match the most recent product ID.
So the output should be something like this:

```
cust_id|latest_Product_id|time_since_last_diff_order_days|
1      |a                |30                             |
2      |b                |92                             |
3      |c                |91                             |
4      |d                |123                            |
```

Here's the query that I tried to use but got an error (error code 1064)

```
SELECT a.cust_id, a.Product_ID as latest_Product_id, DATEDIFF(MAX(a.Order_date),MAX(b.Order_date)) as time_since_last_diff_order_days 
FROM database_customers.cust_orders a
       INNER JOIN
     database_customers.cust_orders b
       on
         a.cust_id = b.cust_id
WHERE a.product_id =! b.prodcut_id;
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find the difference between the most recent date and the previous date that has a product ID that doesn't match the most recent product ID.

You can use `first_value()` to get the last product and then aggregate:

```
select cust_id, last_product_id, max(order_date),
       datediff(max(order_date), max(case when product_id <> last_product_id then order_date end)) as diff_from_last_product
from (select co.*,
             first_value(product_id) over (partition by cust_id order by order_date) as last_product_id
      from cust_orders co
     ) co
group by cust_id, last_product_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this solution it doesn't work either, I added "END" to the end of the case statement and it still doesn't work, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @ShihanahAlhusayni . . . What does "not work" mean?

Comment: @ShihanahAlhusayni . . . What is the error?

Comment: I did more research to try to fix it but it turns out that I'm not able to run it because mysql verion is 5.7.12

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty,, but will do the job

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1
>     (`cust_id` int, `Product_id` varchar(1), `Order_date` datetime)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tab1
>     (`cust_id`, `Product_id`, `Order_date`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'a', '2020-10-02 02:00:00'),
>     (2, 'b', '2020-10-01 02:00:00'),
>     (3, 'c', '2020-09-07 02:00:00'),
>     (4, 'd', '2020-09-02 02:00:00'),
>     (1, 'a', '2020-08-29 02:00:00'),
>     (1, 'f', '2020-08-02 02:00:00'),
>     (2, 'g', '2020-07-01 02:00:00'),
>     (3, 't', '2020-06-06 02:00:00'),
>     (4, 'j', '2020-05-08 02:00:00'),
>     (1, 'w', '2020-04-20 02:00:00')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (SELECT `cust_id`, `Product_id`,`Order_date`,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `cust_id` ORDER BY `Order_date` DESC) rn
> FROM tab1)
> SELECT t1.`cust_id`, t1.`Product_id`, t2.time_since_last_diff_order_days
> FROM 
> (SELECT 
>  `cust_id`, `Product_id`
> FROM
>  CTE
> WHERE rn = 1 ) t1
> JOIN
> ( SELECT `cust_id`,DATEDIFF(MAX(`Order_date`), MIN(`Order_date`)) time_since_last_diff_order_days 
> FROM CTE WHERE rn in (1,2) GROUP BY `cust_id`) t2 ON t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id
> ```

> ```
> cust_id | Product_id | time_since_last_diff_order_days
> ------: | :--------- | ------------------------------:
>       1 | a          |                              34
>       2 | b          |                              92
>       3 | c          |                              93
>       4 | d          |                             117
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8b249e349f1a2691ad0756a8c2cfc96)*